# Receiving a Syntax error: "(" unexpected on my Jenkins file (groovy)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use the following bit of code in a groovy file which I'm running on Jenkins:

```
String cmd = "helm package my-test-chart ; file = sh (script: 'ls*.tgz',returnStdout: true).trim()"
```

But I receive the following error:

```
 Syntax error: "(" unexpected [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // stage
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // node
 [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
 ERROR: script returned exit code 2
 Finished: FAILURE
```

Any help will be appreciated thank you

Comment: If we are talking Groovy, it's `String` not `string`.  And from the syntax here it looks you are mixing shell syntax with jenkins syntax?

Comment: @cfrick sorry I had `String` in my original code have edited it hereto show that. And how do I go about fixing this? I'm pretty new to the whole Jenkins/shell syntax apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to get the output of an sh command:

```
variable_name = sh(script: " your shell command",
                   returnStdout: true)
```

And by the looks of it, I think you have mixed two statements:

```
    String cmd = "helm package my-test-chart"
 file = sh (script: 'ls*.tgz',returnStdout: true).trim()
```

Comment: I amended my script and it now reads.  

    `file = sh(script: 'ls *.tgz'
               returnStdout: true)`

However I'm now getting the error 
    ls: cannot access '*.tgz': No such file or directory

Any help?

Comment: First, see if you are in the correct directory by running `sh("pwd")` . If it is not in the correct directory then put all your commands inside a `dir('path/to/directory'){ // your code}` block. If it is in the correct directory then check if your jenkins user has permission to access that directory.

Comment: My issue wasn't the directory but rather a mistake on my behalf. I had to run the     
    `cmd = "helm package my-test-chart"`, 

before I defined my variable

Answer (score 1):

I may be late to this one, but i found this question when i was having the exact same problem, and the answer was this: I had created a "secret zip" credential in Jenkins, and pointed it at a zip on my laptop. The name of the zip had a parentheses in it - that's where the error was coming from. When i renamed the target zip, and updated the credential in Jenkins, everything worked fine.

So in your case, something is popping out with a parens where it's not expected. Possibly the `ls *.tgz`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you pipeline should change as following.

```
stage('xxxx') {
   steps {
      script {
        String cmd = "helm package my-test-chart"
        file = sh (script: 'ls*.tgz',returnStdout: true).trim()
      }
   }
}
```